# how to run selenium scripts(Which is in GitHub) through Jenkins(Linux server) in actual browser instead of headless

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, github

I want to run my selenium scripts through Jenkins(Linux server) in actual browser but right now it is running in headless mode. I am not able to see the execution of scripts on UI. Can someone help me into this ?

Comment: Yuo will need to make sure that the server running Jenkins has a GUI and a browser that can run the selenium scripts.

Comment: How is your Jenkins job is to configure? Are you running this on a slave agent or Jenkins machine itself ?